# problem install react Aborting installation

Tags: reactjs, installation

In the terminal, I am receiving an error code E404 with message "Aborting installation. npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template-typescrypt has failed." Additionally, I see the following error details:

```
5376 error code E404
5377 error 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cra-template-typescrypt - Not found
5378 error 404
5379 error 404 'cra-template-typescrypt@*' is not in this registry.
```

The generated file package.json has been deleted. What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you received indicates that the package **cra-template-typescrypt** was not found in the npm registry.

There seems to be a typo in the package name. It should be **cra-template-typescript** instead of **cra-template-typescrypt**.